# Reusing a CMake Build of Software on another system

Tags: compiling, cmake

I want to have insight on which directories should I copy from my one system to another system so that I don't have to build using CMake again.

What should be my approach to find a relevant solution for building on one system and copying to another system?

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues/533 is not helpful to me.

Comment: Here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8970979/6213452, Symbolic Links will cause issue.